# Microsoft Entity Framework not showing foreign keys for some tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, entity-framework-5

I built the entity model from the database, using Entity Framework Version 5.0.  The following DDL was used to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Replenishment](
    [replenishmentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [locationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [inventoryItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([replenishmentId] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Replenishment]  
    WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FKReplenishm163678]
    FOREIGN KEY([inventoryItemId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[InventoryItem] ([inventoryItemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Replenishment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FKReplenishm163678]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Replenishment]  
    WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FKReplenishm580804] 
    FOREIGN KEY([locationID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([locationID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Replenishment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FKReplenishm580804]
GO
```

When I build an entity model with the tables Replenishment, Location, and InventoryItem, all three tables show up in the model, but none of the relationships do.

Does anyone know why the foreign keys or the navigation properties don't appear?

============================================================================

Here is the DDL from the associated tables:
Here is the ddl from the other two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
[locationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[addressID] [int] NULL,
[availabilityStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
[inLocationId] [int] NULL,
[locationTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[locationName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[locationDescription] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[locationAnchorX] [int] NULL,
[locationAnchorY] [int] NULL,
[locationImage] [varchar](255) NULL,
[diagramLayerId] [int] NULL,
[locationShapeParameters] [varchar](max) NULL,
[locationHeight] [int] NULL,
    [locationWidth] [int] NULL,
    [locationColor] [varchar](20) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[locationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY     = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FKLocation209934] FOREIGN KEY([inLocationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([locationID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FKLocation209934]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InventoryItem](
[inventoryItemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[itemTaxonomyId] [int] NOT NULL,
[itemDescription] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[itemCode] [varchar](40) NULL,
[batchControlled] [bit] NOT NULL,
[assemblyDefinitionID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [inventoryItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: I extracted the ddl from my working database and inserted it into a new database.  Now the Entity framework found the foreign keys.  I see nothing defective in the working database.  Any suggestion about where to find a problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Are `locationID` and `inventoryItemId` primary keys of `Location` and `InventoryItem` tables?

Comment: Could you include the ddl of Location and InventoryItem as well so we can run a repro?

Comment: Yes, those are the primary keys.  When I recreated the tables from the ddl extracted from the database, I no longer had the problem.  SQL Server diagram tool showed the foreign key relationship with the original (defective) tables.

Comment: Additional ddl added to main section due to limitations in size to the comment.

Comment: I have since recreated the database and do not currently have the problem with the recreated database.  The original database is still bad regarding updating the entity model, but I don't see the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I found the problem.  I had been doing some work with SQL Server authentication and some work with windows Authentication.  The information entered using Windows Authentication was not seen by my Visual Studio, which was connecting using SQL Server authentication.

After further research I found that this was not the case.  I am still bemused by this.